# Typescript declaration for uuidv5, export both enum and default function

Tags: node.js, typescript, node-modules

I'm trying to create a Typescript Declaration for uuidv5, it's my very first declaration for a 3rd party module and they're using a construct I don't understand. The undressed module looks like:

```
function uuidToString(uuid) {
}

function uuidFromString(uuid) {
}

function createUUIDv5(namespace, name, binary) {
}

createUUIDv5.uuidToString = uuidToString;
createUUIDv5.uuidFromString = uuidFromString;

module.exports = createUUIDv5;
```

I tried to create a declaration like this:

```
declare module uuidv5 {
    type uuid = string | Buffer
    enum space { dns, url, oid, x500, null, default }
    type ns = uuid | space

    export interface createUUIDv5 {
        (namespace: ns, name: uuid): uuid;
        (namespace: ns, name: uuid, binary: boolean): uuid;

        uuidToString(uuid: Buffer): string;
        uuidFromString(uuid: string): Buffer;
        createUUIDv5: uuidv5.createUUIDv5;
        space: uuidv5.space;
    }
}

declare const exp: uuidv5.createUUIDv5;
export = exp;
```

Which has almost gotten what I want, except for the fact that I can't access the space enum using

```
var uuidNs = uuidv5(uuidv5.spaces.null, "My Space", true);
                    ------------------
var uuid = uuidv5(uuidNs, "My Space", true);
```

I went through the docs, but can't find a way to add that enum in there while still being able to use it for the type definition at the top...

Comment: Are you trying to export `space` enum from module?

Comment: I think I am. I want to be able to use it from the calling code, right now it doesn't show up nor compile when I try to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
declare module uuidv5 {
    type uuid = string | Buffer
    enum space { dns, url, oid, x500, null, default }
    type ns = uuid | space

    export interface createUUIDv5 {
        (namespace: ns, name: uuid): uuid;
        (namespace: ns, name: uuid, binary: boolean): uuid;

        uuidToString(uuid: Buffer): string;
        uuidFromString(uuid: string): Buffer;
        createUUIDv5: uuidv5.createUUIDv5;
        spaces: typeof uuidv5.space; // notice this line
    }
}

declare const exp: uuidv5.createUUIDv5;
export = exp;
```

I don't recommend to use `declare module uuidv5` format, since it is deprecated. ES6 module compatible ambient module is better.

```
declare module 'uuidv5' {
    type uuid = string | Buffer
    enum space { dns, url, oid, x500, null, default }
    type ns = uuid | space

    interface createUUIDv5 {
        (namespace: ns, name: uuid): uuid;
        (namespace: ns, name: uuid, binary: boolean): uuid;

        uuidToString(uuid: Buffer): string;
        uuidFromString(uuid: string): Buffer;
        createUUIDv5: createUUIDv5;
        spaces: typeof space;
    }
    var exp: createUUIDv5
    export = exp
}
```

In use:

```
import * as uuidv5 from 'uuidv5'

var uuidNs = uuidv5(uuidv5.spaces.null, "My Space", true);
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked perfectly. Once you see the answer it becomes so obvious :).